# How to bring down cpanel hosted site to local for development?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

Site is hosted in cPanel, i want to bring down to local for development work, and i am not getting proper picture how to do this, please advise and the site is build using laravel.

Comment: Usually you can just copy all the files. (Know nothing about laravel)

Comment: I use to work in wordpress, where we can use some plug-in to download the site and setup the site locally using WAMP, do we have any similar kind of way  ?

Comment: In CPanel you can access the directories of your site. You download them all and then see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can download files through FTP account of your hosted website.. 
You can also zip files from file manager in cPanel and download it. After that, unzip it locally. Here are the steps for you:

Login into cPanel account.
 
Go to the File Manager.
Navigate to the folder where the files you want to compress are While holding down your Ctrl key, click on each file that you would like included in the compressed file.
 
Click the "Compress" button at the top right of the page 
 
 
On the "Compress" page, choose which compression you would like to use (such as zip or tar), enter a name for the file, and then click "Compress File(s)". When the files have been compressed successfully, you'll see a success page that lists the compressed files

Answer (score 0):

Compress the whole Laravel folder into `.zip` or `.tar.gz` and download it. Unzip the folder on your local development environment and make necessary changes on the configurations file (`app.php`, `data.php`, `mail.php`) to match your local configuration.